# Custom Trim the WP Post Title

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have several posts which have similar format of titles. The title format follows like this:
"ABC University - Economics"
"XYZ University - Social Sciences"
"KLM BBB College - Business Administration"
so on...

How can I trim the post title until "-". The text after "-" I dont need.
I just want get "ABC University" or "XYZ University" or "KLM BBB College".

I cannot do it with wp_trim_words() function as number of words are not same for every post title.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: this code trims post title by 3 words:
 echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 3, '...');
I want trim post title until hyphen (-)

Comment: does all title has hyphen (-)? and you only want to display trim title or you want to update the db also with that?

Comment: I want to list my posts by titles. But I want these post titles to be in aforementioned format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to trim title till hyphen (-), then you can use PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this.
Here is the code which should work for you:

```
$title = get_the_title();//eg: 'KLM BBB College - Business Administration';
$title_pices = explode("-",$title);
echo $needed_title = trim($title_pices[0]);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use the explode function.

```
$fullstr = 'XYZ University - Social Sciences';
$splitstr = explode(" - ",$fullstr);
echo $splitstr[0];
```

Comment: FYI $splitstr[1] would give you Social Sciences